# The loops "freeze" my site. - How to reduce the number of loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I do the filtering method, it does everything right, but I have a lot of loops before the filtering itself to "freeze" my site for a second - two.
I would like to improve that, but I don't know how it is the best.

In this case, I use jQuery, but I can convert that code to Vanilla JS, that is no a problem.

So,

When I check one of many checkboxes on filtration, that value will be pushed into an array of items, whose parameters I use to filter items.

```
let choosenValuesDesk = []; // array of items
$(".aside-sortwidget input:checkbox").change(function() { // runs when is checkbox touched
            if($(this).is(":checked")) { // add to array
                ...
                choosenValuesDesk.push(chooseMe); // choose me is item, prepared for filtration, variable from above ...
                $(".desktop-slider__item").each(function(i, obj) { // loop slider items for filtration, btw, here is that "freeze"
                        choosenValuesDesk.map((val) => { // loop items from array above to filter items in each function
                                ...
                                if($(this).data().filter.includes(val)) { // if this slider item has value from chosen checkbox value in data attribute
                                    $(this).addClass("keep-this-slide"); // keep slider item
                                } else {
                                    $(this).removeClass("keep-this-slide");
                                    // else remove class and "hide" item...
                                }...
                        }
                }
            } else { // remove from array it's same process from above to uncheck checkbox
            }
});
```

Btw. I use slick-slider filter methods, can that be a problem?

Example of code for success filtration :

```
$(".desktop-slider")
    .slick("slickUnfilter")
    .slick("slickFilter", ".keep-this-slide");
```

Comment: There are multiple closing brackets missing `)` is that a copy-paste error or not.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal, hi, I have reduced code, i I left the most important parts, no errors.